# How can I retrieve data from youtube?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, youtube

I would like to create an app using flutter that interacts with YouTube, the main idea is that the app needs to get some information about latest videos from specific channel or playlist and then having the possibility to watch those videos.
Now I saw that the official YouTube API has a quota limit for each request, I should request to increase this limit but I’m not sure that that’s enough (if I’ll have many users this sure won’t be enough).

I’ve also seen that I could create a scraper but it should run inside a server and always make requests to it from the app.

So I was wondering if either another system exist or if I’m missing something.

Create many api keys or request to every user to create his own api key to use in the app, could be a solution?

Comment: Is [this](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_api) what you are looking for?

Comment: I’ve already seen it, the problem is: is there a better way to retrieve data from yt without using their api? If not, how can I manage requests from thousands users if the quota limit is very low?

Comment: seems like a problem to solve somewhere around your 500th user. use the api. get your code working. prove your idea. then worry about the problems of success.

Comment: If I want to implement also a search bar, so the user is capable of searching a specific video, the problem will appear with a lower number of users